# How can jQuery work in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know jQuery was made because JavaScript does not workin all browsers.  However, jQuery is a library built with JavaScript, so how can it work in all browsers?

Comment: It doesn't. The supported browsers are detailed on [jQuery's homepage](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Like many other people, you have been misled. jQuery "was made" because the person writing it had no clue what they were doing; they still do not. At the time it was devised there was no need for jQuery already, syntactic sugar aside. Much less there is need for jQuery now, as language and DOM implementations are becoming increasingly standards-compliant. While jQuery's selector approach is short when writing code, it is comparably inefficient and error-prone behind the scenes. For that reason, jQuery surely does *not* work in all browsers.

Comment: @PointedEars, I don't disagree with your opinion, but there is real benefit to using jQuery for some projects, outside of not knowing what you're doing.  Yes, I completely agree that there is less and less of a need for it these days, and that enabling support for browsers not generally used causes it to run slow, and that it does not work in all browsers.

Comment: @PointedEars, For me, the benefit is doing things quickly, and in a way that will be broadly compatible.

Comment: @Brad Given its apparent disadvantages, what exactly is the benefit of using jQuery? To write code that *looks* cool?

Comment: @PointedEars, Who cares about code that looks cool?  Certainly not me.  Readable, understandable code, yes, but that has nothing to do with "looking cool".

Comment: I can't understand what the OP is saying? Can anyone elaborate?!

Comment: @David, My read is that he was mislead on the purpose of jQuery, thinking that it was meant to provide JavaScript capability when it was not available or enabled.  This lead to confusion about how jQuery worked internally.

Comment: @Brad But while the "doing things quickly" part is true, the second part certainly is not. Its design simply does not allow that, and that is why there needs to be a new jQuery version whenever a new browser comes about (dropping support for the older versions), while other libraries happily continue to work without those updates in all predecessors.

Comment: Nothing works in "all browsers"; javascript works in modern browsers and many outdated browsers as long as they have javascript turned on, and jQuery works in a subset of browsers that javascript works in, including every browser you're likely to get visitors using. The reason you keep seeing jQuery called "cross-browser" is that is glosses over differences between browsers. For example, one browser might do something by calling method A, and another by calling method B. What jQuery does is test to see if method A exists, and if it does, use it, otherwise use method B.

Comment: @st-boost Your logic is flawed. While nothing works in all browsers, script code, even that of a library that builds widgets dynamically, can be written so that it degrades gracefully. The so-called "differences in browsers" are virtually non-existent since about 10 years (with broad DOM Level 2 support), and jQuery is *unable* to gloss (cross?) them because of its internal design that hinges on selectors and overloading. Since I know from experience that those discussions lead to nowhere, and SO is not a discussion forum anyway, EOD for me. Go read some comp.lang.javascript for enlightenment.

Comment: @PointedEars, jQuery is like the beer I just had.  Deeply flawed, a bit heavy, but gets the job done on this particular night.  Would I always drink this beer?  No way.  Does it work well enough for tonight?  You bet.  Cheers.

Comment: writing code with jQuery looks cool anyway ;)

Comment: @PointedEars  you are espousing another myth just like the one in OP. jQuery team is fanatical about backward compatibility and supports older browser back as far as IE6

Comment: @PointedEars I'm sitting here laughing because I really can't figure out what you think I said. I explained the concept of graceful degradation to the OP, and you jumped in to say my logic is flawed (what logic?) because code can be written to degrade gracefully (isn't that what I just said?). And I'm sure I'm reading the rest of it wrong, because you seem to be saying that there is no difference between browsers, and that jQuery is unable to account for browser differences because of its "internal design" - which is not only inconsistent, but wrong on both accounts.

Comment: You have misunderstood something: jQuery won't work in browsers that don't support JavaScript, because, as you said yourself, it is written in said language. jQuery is rather providing an abstraction layer for the DOM API and related concepts (such as event handling), which can differ quite a lot in browsers (especially IE vs rest).

Answer (score 3):

Because jQuery is written with the same hacks that ordinary developers would be forced to use if they didn't have jQuery available. It's designed to take into account all the variance between browsers and standardize their behavior as much as possible. There's nothing special or magical about it - it's just a lot of hard work to do the same things you'd be doing otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery can only work when a browser supports JavaScript.

The purpose of jQuery is that different browsers sometimes offer different APIs (such as for AJAX/XHR stuff), which jQuery normalizes to be a single standard API.  That's the real benefit of jQuery.

Comment: Why the -1?  Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript only works in browsers that have javascript. jQuery is just a library built on top of it to give extended functionality.

Comment: :P Now I'm sure. (I edited it)